# Vite Build Configuration to generate minified files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vite, rollupjs

I am developing a vite-vue application.

`vite build` command minifies the ts and css/scss and places them in `dist/main-xxxxxx.js` and `dist/main-xxxxxx.css` and correctly linked with `dist/index.html`.

But it does not modify the file name to `main-xxxxxx.min.js` and `main-xxxxxx.min.css`

How can I modify the `vite.config.ts` to get the filenames renamed as `main-xxxxxx.min.js` and `main-xxxxxx.min.css`?

My `vite.config.ts` is as follows

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: { sourcemap: true },
  css: { devSourcemap: true },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: '/src' }],
  },
})
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi. The same issue has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228325/how-to-set-a-custom-output-name-for-script-with-vite-build

Comment: Hi @VladislavUtkin Thanks for the reply. But what I need is to append `.min` to the file name, like `main-xxxxxx.min.js` and `main-xxxxxx.min.css`

Comment: try to put .min between keywords in brackets. Probably it will help 
              assetFileNames: `assets/[name].min.[ext]`,